# Calculate $ϕ(\lambda):=\mathbb{E}[e^{-\lambda X}]$ for $\lambda>0$ and $\mu=0 $

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, expected-value

Hey I have this small problem:

Let $X∼N((\mu, σ^2)$ normal distributed random variables on the probability space $(Ω, F, P)$.
I have to calculate $ϕ(\lambda):=\mathbb{E}[e^{-\lambda X}]$ for $ \lambda>0$ and $\mu=0 $.

So I have calculated:
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{-\lambda X}]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi σ^2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{σ^2}}dx=e^\frac{\lambda}{σ^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi σ^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x^3}dx=e^\frac{\lambda}{σ^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi σ^2}}\left[\frac{1}{3x^2}e^{x^3}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$

However this integral is infinite.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The mistake is that $e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}} = e^{-\lambda x - \frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}} \ne e^{(-\lambda x)(-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2})}$.

Answer (score 1):

What you did wrong is that
$$
e^{-\lambda x}e^{-x^2/\sigma^2}\neq e^{\lambda/\sigma^2}e^{x^3}
$$
does not hold
(it seems that you that $e^ae^b=e^{ab}$ instead of $e^{a+b}$).

Comment: A verb is missing in your last sentence.